# Internet connection sharing or NAT in server 2012 essentials

Tags: windows-server-2012, nat

I'm configuring a new network, where a windows 2012 server will be the route to the internet, doing some nat for the clients on its own LAN nic.

Installed and removed RRAS with routing and VPN now a few times, folowing some articles but somehow it doesnt want to work each time different errors. which where not googable (is that a new word?).

However when i go to the Network sharing center, click on my WAN adapter, click properties.
Then on top go to sharing..then from there i can also enable 
"allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection"

The setting is also present on the LAN nic, and reminds me of older windows clients.

Now i wonder how is this different from 2012 routing role (with NAT) option ?

Answer (score 0):

Routing is different then internet ip sharing i found later.
internet ip sharing requires a specific ip on the LAN side while routing with NAT does not.